# How do I send data along with APITestCase client.patch() in DjangoRestFramework?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, http-patch

My TestCase:

```
class MyApiTests(APITestCase):
    def test_retrieve(self):
        resp = self.client.patch('/my/endpoint/', data={
            'name': 'new name',
            'age': 25,
            'some_array': [{
                'my_subobject_name': 'foo'
            }]
        }
```

In my viewset, if I grab `data['some_array']`, I get:

`u"{'my_subobject_name': 'foo'}"`.

**Why is it a string instead of an array with one dictionary?**

If I send a stringified version of

```
{
    'name': 'new name',
    'age': 25,
    'some_array': [{
        'my_subobject_name': 'foo'
    }]
}
```

via my browser, DRF works fine, and `some_array` will be a an array with one dictionary inside of it, as expected.

**What is the correct way to send a complex data structure along with a `patch()` in an APITestCase unit test?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `format='json'` argument in the patch function call i.e.

```
class MyApiTests(APITestCase):
    def test_retrieve(self):
        resp = self.client.patch('/my/endpoint/', data={
            'name': 'new name',
            'age': 25,
            'some_array': [{
                'my_subobject_name': 'foo'
            }]
        }, format='json')
```